# How to set a CSS property with a variable in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the CSS property of width as the same size as the browser's current width. To do this, I did `var setWidth = $(window).width()`, but I don't know how to apply this to my current code, which is something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#backgroundImg").css("width", ""); 
});
```

Is there any way to do this? I'm new to JQuery so I might just be really amateur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var setWidth = $(window).width();
    $("#backgroundImg").css("width", setWidth + 'px'); 
});
```

or you can use [`$.width`](http://api.jquery.com/width/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#backgroundImg').width( $(window).width() )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

update code to following

```
$("#backgroundImg").css("width", setWidth + "px");
```

Answer (score 0):

One option: $("#backgroundImg").css("width","100%");

with your variable option do: var setWidth = $(window).width() +'px';

so your code would be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#backgroundImg").css("width", setWidth);
```

});

Comment: The first option is incorrect. Second option is correct with a small error - just add "px" as well

Answer (score 0):

This should make the background match the browser's current width:

```
$( "#backgroundImg" ).width( setWidth )
```

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/width/)